# Apple idfa in Unity via Plugin

Tags: c#, ios, xcode

I borrowed this code from another stack overflow answer:

example.mm

```
const char* getIdfa()
{
    if([[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled])
    {
        NSString * idfa = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
        //return (const char*)[idfa UTF8String]; // ##### malloc error I uncomment this line #####
    }
    return nil;
}
```

iOSplugin.cs

```
#if UNITY_IOS
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern string getIdfa();
#endif
```

Xcode build settings that can affect the issue:
Project format: xcode 3.1 compatible
Obj-C Automatic Reference Counting: Yes

If I uncomment this line:

```
return (const char*)[fdsa UTF8String];
```

then I get the following error:

```
(531,0x19e9ef000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1357d44e1: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

There are some references to a function called cocoaToMonoString which is supposed to fix this problem, but I can't find any examples or documentation about it.

How do I return a string from Xcode back into Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[idfa UTF8String]
This is a reference to the internal byte array inside the NSString.
It can't be passed back to Unity/C#.

Add this function:

```
static const char* MakeStringCopy(const char* string)
{
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    strcpy(res, string);
    return res;
}
```

and return:

```
return MakeStringCopy([idfa UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a two cents contribution.

Now you can obtain IDFA (or GAID for android) using [Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync.html):

```
Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync(
        (string advertisingId, bool trackingEnabled, string error) =>
            Debug.Log("advertisingId " + advertisingId + " " + trackingEnabled + " " + error)
);
```

Also that method returns a boolean value indicating true in case of success or false if the current platform doesn't support advertising identifiers.

Comment: Agreed, this is better if you're using Unity 5.3 or later.  When this question was originally posted, that wasn't a guarantee, but now, yeah, this is probably the better answer.